# Handling complex numbers in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, complex-numbers

I doubt an Excel spreadsheet can handle this but it's worth asking, since I have been trying and searching for a long time with no success.

Entering this into a cell:

```
=complex(abs(-1.5*(-1.5)^(-1.5))),0)
```

and the cell output is `#NUM!`

The output should be:  `0.8164966`

Comment: you are trying the square root of a negative number as real number part. that will not succeed...

Comment: @Brian but it does not work in Excel.  Even `-1.5 ^ -1.5` returns a `#NUM` error.

Comment: the calculation requires logic including the imaginary numbers, thats not how Excel calculates it.

Comment: Essentially I mean `=abs(-1.5*(-1.5)^(-1.5)))` and I suspect I have to use the `complex()` function somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with this a bit and didn't get anywhere - this article may explain why.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180114135902/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62979.html)

it's complicated, and I think it's more than an excel problem

Answer (score 1):

The following pdf has a nice write-up for using complex number functions in excel.

https://ccnet.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/course.cgi?cc=ee246&action=handout_download&handout_id=ID11300955936304

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have made a mistake inserting the parentheses.

The correct form is:

```
=COMPLEX(ABS((-1.5)*((1.5)^(-1.5))),0)

=0.816496580927726
```

This runs well in Excel 2013.

Comment: Reproduced in Excel 2011.  I also agree about the parentheses.